# libgdx how exactly do I not render part of a big tiled map

Tags: camera, libgdx, render, tiled

I have read many threads about loading a large tiled map. The methods are dividing the big map into different "regions" and check if the region is needed. If the region is needed, then check if all cells in the regions are needed. If the cells are not in camera bound, then they are not needed. Then I have to do something to not render the not needed cells and regions.

However I don't understand how to do the last part.

Do I set every not needed cell into null and then throw the remaining cells to render method, then after the camera move a little bit, load the whole map again and do all the checkings, then set every not needed cells to null and render it (like previous part)?

Or is there a method to directly not rendering the not needed cells to skip the loading map process?

Comment: Are you using TiledMap or are you making your own tile map? If you are loading a TiledMap this problem is taken care of. If you are making your own then you are looking at it wrong. Instead of not drawing unneeded parts of the map, just draw only needed parts of the map. Before anyone can have a chance to help you, we need to know what you are doing. Show us some code.

Comment: I am using TiledMap from mapeditor. But when I try to render the map using orthogonaltiledmaprenderer, it will draw the whole map. Even the part outside the camera. So I don't know how to only render the wanted part after checking each cell.

Comment: The code is basically using a control panel to move a ball across the tile map. When the ball moves, camera and control panel will move with it. The tile map is big because I am trying to make open world game. So I have to not render unwanted part.